# How to run trigger another job outside pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three jobs which are in pipeline. Whenever anyone fails due to an internal account lock these have to trigger post-build action.In POst build action i mentioned Trigger when build is failed.  I wrote a robot test to unlock the account and I wrote a shell script to call this test.
I am calling this template in both jobs in post-build action and building it on the same node.But what i found is this post build action is kept in pending state and jenkins is triggering downstream project. How to make Jenkins to run post build action when the current job fails?

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the seed job's propagate property.

Simple example:

```
Map jobResults = [:]

pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build seedjob 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    String seedJobName = 'testjob1'

                    def seedJob = build job: seedJobName, propagate: false
                    jobResults[seedJobName] = seedJob.result

                    echo "Result of ${seedJobName}: ${seedJob.result}"
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build seedjob 2') {
            steps {
                script {
                    String seedJobName = 'testjob2'

                    def seedJob = build job: seedJobName, propagate: false
                    jobResults[seedJobName] = seedJob.result

                    echo "Result of ${seedJobName}: ${seedJob.result}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success { 
            script {
                if(jobResults['testjob1'] == 'FAILURE') {
                    echo "Running another job"
                    build job: 'another-job1', propagate: true
                }

                if(jobResults['testjob2'] == 'FAILURE') {
                    echo "Running another job"
                    build job: 'another-job2', propagate: true
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```